# Could not install istio 1.6.3 demo profile on AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, istio, amazon-eks

I install with this

```
istioctl install --set profile=demo
```

and I got this error

```
2020-06-23T06:53:12.111697Zerrorinstallerfailed to create "PeerAuthentication/istio-s
ystem/grafana-ports-mtls-disabled": Timeout: request did not complete within requested timeout 30s
✘ Addons encountered an error: failed to create "PeerAuthentication/istio-system/grafana-ports-mtls-
disabled": Timeout: request did not complete within requested timeout 30s
- Pruning removed resources                                                                         
Error: failed to apply manifests: errors occurred during operation
```

Comment: Could you add command which you used to install it? Could you try to use `istioctl install --set profile=demo --set addonComponents.grafana.enabled=true` and tell me what´s the result? Did you try to use [istio operator](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/standalone-operator/)?

Comment: FWIW - I found this as I am troubleshooting the exact same issue with istio 1.6.1. I have my installation automated with 50+ successful deploys, but now they all fail today, which makes me pretty sure the issue is some change on my side. I am running AWS / k8s 1.15, and am currently suspecting SG / firewall rules. If I find something useful I will reply.

To get better suggestions / help, you should add a bit more info here, such as environment, cluster, etc; as well as how you deployed and what you did so far. I'm guessing your setup based on your tags, but some narrative would be useful.

Comment: @jt97 I tried command as your suggestion. It's still didn't work. I'll try to istio operator and will update to you later. Thank you

Comment: I updated my question for command that I used to install.

Comment: I've tried istio operator and It's work! Thank you @jt97

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there is something wrong either with

- istioctl install and aws
- your cluster

You could try to create new eks cluster and check if it works, if it´s not I would suggest to open new thread on [istio github](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues).

---

If you have same problem as @Possathon Chitpidakorn, you can use istio operator as a **workaround** to install istio, more about it below.

### [istio operator](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2019/introducing-istio-operator/#the-operator-api)

> Every operator implementation requires a custom resource definition (CRD) to define its custom resource, that is, its API. Istio’s operator API is defined by the IstioControlPlane CRD, which is generated from an IstioControlPlane proto. The API supports all of Istio’s current configuration profiles using a single field to select the profile. For example, the following IstioControlPlane resource configures Istio using the demo profile:

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: IstioControlPlane
metadata:
  namespace: istio-operator
  name: example-istiocontrolplane
spec:
  profile: demo
```

> You can then customize the configuration with additional settings. For example, to disable telemetry:

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: IstioControlPlane
metadata:
  namespace: istio-operator
  name: example-istiocontrolplane
spec:
  profile: demo
  telemetry:
    enabled: false
```

### How to [install istio with istio operator](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/standalone-operator/)

> Prerequisites

- Perform any necessary [platform-specific setup](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/platform-setup/).
- Check the [Requirements for Pods and Services](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/deployment/requirements/).
- Install the [istioctl command](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/diagnostic-tools/istioctl/).

> Deploy the **Istio operator:**

```
istioctl operator init
```

This command runs the operator by creating the following resources in the istio-operator namespace:

- The operator custom resource definition
- The operator controller deployment
- A service to access operator metrics
- Necessary Istio operator RBAC rules

> See the available istioctl operator init flags to control which namespaces the >controller and Istio are installed into and the installed Istio image sources and versions.

---

You can alternatively deploy the operator using Helm:

```
$ helm template manifests/charts/istio-operator/ \
  --set hub=docker.io/istio \
  --set tag=1.6.3 \
  --set operatorNamespace=istio-operator \
  --set istioNamespace=istio-system | kubectl apply -f -
```

Note that you need to download [the Istio release](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/#download) to run the above command.

---

> To install the Istio demo configuration profile using the operator, run the following command:

```
$ kubectl create ns istio-system
$ kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: example-istiocontrolplane
spec:
  profile: demo
EOF
```

> The controller will detect the IstioOperator resource and then install the Istio components corresponding to the specified (demo) configuration.